# Wrong pip3 version

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I installed my python3.5.1 with Anaconda but the pip3 version is wrong and the package installation location is wrong.

```
pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Users/Ruidong/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

I do have the python3

```
which python3
//anaconda/bin/python3
which pip3
/Users/Ruidong/anaconda/bin/pip3
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the first line of the file `/Users/Ruidong/anaconda/bin/pip3`?

Comment: #!/Users/Ruidong/anaconda/bin/python

Comment: which value are you expecting as an output from 'pip3 --version' ?